# Iam using light box code from w3school..the modal div with position fixed is going off screen In microsoft edge but in chrome it fits the screen HOW

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge, lightbox

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
</style>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/cd/c5/28/cdc52828015a52dfa58cbab3c7c32789.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/40/37/86/403786a9e3002601b0908a2ca71af854.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/750x/0c/df/d3/0cdfd3925a07426b59cc0e4efc41feed.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/750x/79/29/4a/79294a543badd88eef95456b9eec3ebc.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <div style="width:100%;height:300px;background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/cc/e2/6a/cce26ae2b863e1a2ecf593a18474bb6f.jpg);background-position:center;background-size: cover; "></div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">asd / 4</div>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/40/37/86/403786a9e3002601b0908a2ca71af854.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/750x/0c/df/d3/0cdfd3925a07426b59cc0e4efc41feed.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/750x/79/29/4a/79294a543badd88eef95456b9eec3ebc.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

*Question:Iam using light box code from w3school..the modal div with position fixed is going off screen In microsoft edge but in chrome it fits the screen  HOW*

Is there any web extension like -ms that I should apply to my CSS ??

if this IE browser issue please help me with some fix

**Width:92%**
fits the screen In Microsoft edge
Can anyone please Help??

Comment: Which version of Edge browser are you using? I test your code snippet in Edge and Chrome, the results are the same as this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmFEw.jpg. My Edge version is 91.0.864.59. Please update the Edge browser to the latest and test again. If the issue still exists, please provide a code snippet which can **reproduce the issue**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that the light box's width/height is bigger in Chrome as it is in Edge?
I just tested your snippet in both Edge and Chrome and don't see a difference.

What you can do is make use of a css postprocessor which, hopefully for you, solves the issue.

Can you add a link to a screenshot of both browsers?

Comment: chrome: https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipNAbY3Wg4OYyYG1M_zPrhPYUk4BFEJmKL5IYJjt

Comment: microsoft edge:https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipN2xaZIROuQF9TapRHkKvmUY5eai9FITmu3TiGl

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I can't see the images you used in the link. Is this problem solved or do you still have some errors?